# D3 data undefined when attempting nested selection

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm having trouble working with json data in D3. The file is read properly, judging from the fact that it appears when I `console.log`, and seems to be formatted right based on the way all the examples I found. But, when I try to do a nested selection using `.data(function(json_data){return json_data.accessibility;})` I get: "cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

My function:

```
//load scenario json data
d3.json("./SupportTool/scenario1result.json", function(error, json_data){
if(error) {return console.warn(error)};
console.log(json_data); //works

// add main SVG block
var svg = d3.select(d3id)
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 300)
    .attr('height', 75)
    .attr('id', 'svgblock');

// add an SVG group element for each scenario
var series = svg.selectAll('g.series')
    .data(d3.keys(json_data))
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'series');

var circles = series.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function(json_data){return json_data.accessibility;})
    .enter()
    .append("circle");
var circleAttributes = circles
    .attr("cx", 20)
    .attr("cy", 20)
    .attr("r", 20)
    .style("color","blue");       });
```

My json data:

```
{
"meta":[{"sc":"1"},{"stratid":"1"}],

"accessibility":[
    {"pop400":"77"},{"pop800":"86"},{"jobs800":"78"},{"pop400tr":"41"},{"pop800tr":"69"},{"jobs800tr":"80"}
],

"housing":[
    {"newcom":"0"},{"redev":"100"},
    {"apt5":"6"},{"apt4":"65"},{"twn":"14"},{"sglf":"15"},

    {"urb":"0"},{"urbhec":"0"}

],

"transport":[

    {"walk":"55"},{"transit":"18"},{"auto":"27"},
    {"vkt":"11000"},

    {"kmtr":"502"},{"form":"grid"},
    {"lanekm":"3250"},

    {"ghgtr":"67"},{"ghgres":"75"}
],

"costs":[
    {"roadcapbils":null,"roadcap":null},
    {"transitcapbils":null,"transitcap":null},
    {"watercapbils":null,"watercap":null},
    {"firecapbils":null,"firecap":null},
    {"reccapbils":null,"reccap":null},
    {"educapbils":null,"educap":null}
],

"opcosts":[
    {"roadopbils":null,"roadop":null},
    {"transitoppbils":null,"transitop":null},
    {"wateropbils":null,"waterop":null},
    {"fireopbils":null,"fireop":null},
    {"parksopbils":null,"parksop":null}
] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having comes from the fact that you are binding data to `circles` using a function of the data already bound to `series`:

```
var circles = series.selectAll("circle")
```

`series` already has data bound to it from `.data(d3.keys(json_data))`. Thus, when you log the objects being passed one at a time to the `.data()` for `circles`, you just get the keys of `json_data`, i.e.

```
["meta", "accessibility", "housing", "transport", "costs", "opcosts"]
```

Since this is a list of Strings, they do not have any property called `accessibility`, hence your error.

My guess is that you are trying to append circles for each item in `json_data.accessibility`, which your code will do if you just replace that line with

```
.data(json_data.accessibility)
```

which will pass

```
[{"pop400":"77"},{"pop800":"86"},{"jobs800":"78"},{"pop400tr":"41"},{"pop800tr":"69"},{"jobs800tr":"80"}]
```

to `data`. This code works on my  machine, and draws six circles on the page.

One final note is that you should be careful with your variable names. In the function you pass to data, you are redefining `json_data` as a local variable in that function, which means you can't access your actual JSON data in that function.

Comment: Thank-you! It works great when I replace the entire series and circles chunks with
`var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
     .data(json_data.accessibility)
     .enter()
     .append("circle");`